# How do I overlay an image and some text onto a UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to overlay a signature image along with some text on to a fax image.
I have the following code that I am using so far:

```
CGRect faxImageRect = CGRectZero;
CGRect signatureRect = CGRectZero; //need to add a logo and some text here
//faxImage is a fax UIImage
//signature is a Logo UIImage

faxImageRect.size = faxImage.size;
signatureRect.size = signature.size;

// Adjust the signature's location within the fax image
signatureRect.origin = desirableLocation;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(faxImage.size);
[faxImage drawInRect:faxImageRect];
[signature drawInRect:signatureRect];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I need to write some text as part of my signature. Arial size 10. How do I do that? I am getting really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout `– drawAtPoint:withFont:` of `NSString(UIStringDrawing)`, some code like this should work:

```
[@"My Signature" drawAtPoint:somePoint withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0]];
```